# $\lambda$ matrices and elementary operations

Tags: matrices

When performing elementary operations on $\lambda$ matrices, why can't we multiply a row or a column by a polynomial of $\lambda$ unlike in regular matrices?
 We can only multiply by a nonzero constant.

Comment: What are $\lambda$-matrices?

Comment: A matrix whose elements are polynomials in the variable $\lambda$.